# Simple date formatting giving wrong time

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a String to a Date and it giving me right date where as time is wrong.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aaa");

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse("2015-08-20 05:00 AM");
    Log.e("date", date+"");           // Logcat printing Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Error",e.toString());
}
```

As you can see irrespective of the time every time parsed date time showing `00:00:00`
What I want is `Thu Aug 20 05:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015`

Comment: Try setting the timezone.

Comment: @JanithaR I changed to `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a",Locale.US);` but still same problem.

Comment: I believe your problem is that you're specifying am/pm, but you're using uppercase `H`'s for the hour, which indicate a 24-hour clock. Change them to lowercase `h`'s.

Comment: @MikeM.You are right. Actually I didn't knew about difference between `H` and `h`. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3177222 That's locale, I said timezone. Like this `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("_timezone here_"));` Also like Mike said remove `aaa` and see if the time will come up correctly in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was that your pattern String specified am/pm, but was using uppercase `H`'s for the hour characters. These indicate a 24-hour clock, which obviously doesn't use am/pm. Change the hour characters to lowercase `h`'s, which indicate the hour in am/pm (0-11).

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa");
```

The [docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) explain the various acceptable pattern characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
String dateToStr = format.format(new Date());
System.out.println("dateToStr=>" + dateToStr);

try {
        Date strToDate = format.parse(dateToStr);
        System.out.println("strToDate=>" + strToDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its related to time zone issues, at what time zone is your input?, i'd suggest to make sure your paramater is on UTC timezone and then using formatter like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aaa");
formatter .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: As Mike already said my problem was in `HH:mm aaa`. I was using AM/PM and `HH` both where as `HH` is for 24 hour clock. So I changed to `hh:mm aaa` and my problem solved.

Comment: @user3177222 accept his answer then :) I will leave my answer here so that maybe it would help someone else

Comment: Well I'm still waiting for his answer to accept :P 
He solved it in comment only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you missed some lines of code

```
SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa",  Locale.getDefault());
mFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("India"));
Date startDate = mFormatter.parse("2015-08-20 05:00 AM");
```

This code working fine for me.